# pyTelegramBotApi unable to get message_id

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am using pyTelegramBotApi and I would like to get the id of the message sent to a chat and then forward it to other chats the problem is that i always get this exception `'AsyncTask' object has no attribute 'message_id'` while the message is sent correctly
how to solve?

```
bot = telebot.AsyncTeleBot(bot_token)

res = bot.send_message(cid,message)
try:
    message_id = res.message_id
    print(message_id)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `send_message()` is an AsyncTask, you'll need to [`.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Event.wait) until the event is done;

```
res = bot.send_message(cid,message)
try:
    result = res.wait()
    print(result.message_id)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

More [telegram-bot docs](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#asynchronous-delivery-of-messages).